# React dynamic Datalist - Options are not populated via api response

Tags: reactjs, datalist, html-datalist, dynamic-data-list

Please find the issue below.

Initially data will be empty array, so the **loading** option will be displayed in data list. But when the datalist is clicked, an api call will be made to get the data. Once the response is received from api, setData will be called with the response. Eventually datalist **options** should be updated with the response, but it is always showing **loading** itself. That **loading** is not removing at all.

**Expected Behavior**: datalist options should be auto populated with api response.

**Current Behavior**: datalist is always showing **loading**.

Below is the code for reference.
Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

````
const DataList = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const onClickHandler = async() => {
    const response = await fetchData(); //gets data from api
    setData(response);
  }

 return (
  <div className="custom-data-list-container">
     <input
       type="search"
       list="list"
       autoComplete="on"
       value={text}
       onChange={onChangeHandler}                
       onClick={onClickHandler}
       onBlur={onBlurHandler}
     />
     <datalist id="list" className="custom-data-list">
        {data.length > 0 ? ( // load options data
          <div>
            {data.map((d, idx) => (
              <option key={`${d}${idx}`} value={d} />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : ( // show loading text
          <div>
               <option value=" "> Loading </option>
          </div>
        )}
     </datalist>
  </div>
)
}```
````

Comment: Have you checked the value of response ?

Comment: Yes, it is having records.